# python - make my regex less greedy?

Tags: python, regex

I am looking for some Python regex which I can use to extract a string from a file which has a single line of text (which is actually JavaScript code).

An example of what I'm looking for is to extract the variable name that a substring is being taken from:

So if the line of text I was parsing is:

```
"var foo = bar.substr(baz % qux, morestuffhere"
```

I want my match to be **bar**. I'm using the following, which matches after the equals sign and before the modulo operator:

```
pat = r"\s?\=\s?(.*?)\.substr\(\s?baz\s?\%\s?"
```

This works great if the string of interest is on a new line, however when part of a longer string it fails. [See here for a failed example:](https://regex101.com/r/jnWDnZ/1)

I think the issue is being less greedy with my regex? Although not sure. Pointers appreciated.

Comment: Use `\S*?` instead of `.*?`

Comment: @revo that works! i love it when things are so simple :)

Comment: Why do you even care to match the whole line? If you are really only interested in the variable name use this (with `re.search`, not `re.match`): `(\w*)\.substr\(` . Example here: https://regex101.com/r/jnWDnZ/4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like revo says in comment you need to be more specific for your match group.

`.*?` take all type of character

`\S*?` take non space character

`\w*?` take word character

so you can try this :

```
\s?\=\s?(\w*?)\.substr\(\s?baz\s?\%\s?
```

Comment: thanks for the detail, my understanding is better now